# Maintaining reliable service state history

Tags: azure-service-fabric

The [Reliable Services Overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-introduction/) topic has a section, at the bottom, called *When to use Reliable Services APIs*. In there, one list item says:

> - Your application needs to maintain change history for its units of state*.

The star at the end is explained just a little bit further down:

> * Features available at SDK general availability.

The SDK has reached general availability by now, but I cannot find any information about how to make use of the *"Maintain change history for its units of state"*-feature or even a suggestion of what that actually means.

I'm asking here, in hope that someone can shed any light on this. I'm interested in knowing whether this feature is indeed available, or if not when it is supposed to be available, or if it has been abandoned.

Some insights on the intended design and functionality of this feature would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It describes the scenarios in which you might use the reliable collections. It can be used to keep multiple versions of an object and build a history of changes. (like delta's or snapshots)
This way you can create an event source. (it would require some coding on your end though)

Unit of state: entry in the State manager

Comment: I don't think that this is what they meant. If it were then why would they have marked it as a "feature available at SDK GA"? Something like what you describe could indeed be done in the preview version, in fact such a design has very little to do with the Service Fabric. It could be implemented anywhere and I therefore see no point in mentioning it as an "upcoming feature".